# SAML2 No RelayState was detected so message was not expected to have an InResponseTo attribute

Tags: saml-2.0

Kentor - Using the SampleMvcApplication with success through their StubIdp but when I try with Clareity I receive the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about the implementations ( Kentor, SampleMvcApplication, StubIdP, Clareity )it looks as if:

- Your Identity Provider implementation does not return a 'RelayState' parameter in the body of the HTTP POST along with the SAMLResponse.
- Your Identity Provider implementation has added an InResponseTo attribute in the SAMLResponse element
- Your Service Provider implementation interprets this as an IdP initiated SSO since it does not see a 'RelayState' parameter
- Your Service Provider throws an error since it doesn't make sense for an SAMLResponse in an IdP initiated SSO flow to have an InResponseTo. InResponseTo refers to an AuthenticationRequest which is only there in a normal SP initiated SSO.

To get more help, you should tell us a little about the implementation you are using and your configuration.